# Who this part refers to?

Tags: word-usage, phrases

I’d like to ask about the sentence I’m not sure about in The Engineer’s Thumbs by Conan Doyle.

> .. that of Mr. Hatherley’s thumb, and that of Colonel Warburton’s
>   madness. Of these the latter may have afforded a finer field for ***an
>   acute and original observer***,

This part is the beginning of the stories and Watson describes, as he often does, how he chose a particular episode and how he didn’t pick up other ones
.
What I don’t get is whom this “an acute and original observer” refers to. That the indefinite article “an” is used here can’t mean this refers to Holmes, can it? Then this has to mean one of the readers. So I take what being said with this part is like “the latter episode would offer better entertainment to sharp readers but..”  Or is it actually refers to Holms like “an acute and original observer (like Sherlock Homes)”? I don’t know.
Could someone teach me how I should interpret this?  Thanks.

Comment: It's referring to accuate and original observers in general. And since Holmes is certainly one of these types of people, it implies him as well.